# Compilation error option-unknown - can anyone help me?

Tags: unicode-math

everyone.
I am trying to compile a file in Miktex but it shows this message:

```
! keyvalue error: "option-unknown"
! 
! Unknown option 'vargreek-shape' for package unicode-math.
! 
! See the keyvalue documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
```

Can you explain to me what it is and how to fix it?
Sorry i am completely new to latex and just found this website.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, i.e. the simplest TeX document which you can construct that generates the same error.

Answer (score 11):

Sorry for my slightly misleading comment yesterday I deleted it and reposting a fixed version as an answer.

The error  means that you have

```
\usepackage[vargreek-shape]{unicode-math}
```

or

```
\usepackage[vargreek-shape=xxx]{unicode-math}
```

when there is no option of that name.

There Is an option listed in the manual (I'll ping the author to get that fixed) but the option was removed at the last release.

The change history available in README.md at at

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math

says

> - v0.8d (2017/01/25)
>
>   - `vargreek-shape=TeX` and `vargreek-shape=unicode` package options
>       dropped; for consistency and compatibility, `\phi` and `\epsilon`
>       should and will now behave the same as in `TeX

`.