# Compilation error "option-unknown" - unicode-math

Tags: errors, compiling, unicode-math

I am trying to use a CV template I got online. I really like it, but I am a bit of a noob and don't know how to resolve the errors when I compile.
I get this error first, I am not sure if there may be any more:

> unicode-math.sty 385
>   ! keyvalue error: "option-unknown"
>   ! 
>   ! Unknown option 'vargreek-shape' for package unicode-math.
>   ! 
>   ! See the keyvalue documentation for further information.
>   ! 
>   ! For immediate help type H .
>   !...............................................
>   l.385 \ProcessKeysOptions {unicode-math}

I have tried to look at resolutions online for similar problems, none of which helped very much. Is there a way I can modify it to make it compile?

This is the main code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} 
\fontdir[fonts/] % Specify the location of the included fonts
\colorlet{awesome}{awesome-red}
\renewcommand{\acvHeaderSocialSep}{\quad\textbar\quad} 
\name{Claud D.}{Park}
\address{246-1002, Gwangmyeongmayrouge Apt. 86, Cheongna lime-ro, Seo-gu, Incheon-si, 404-180, Rep. of KOREA}
\mobile{(+82) 10-9030-1843}
\email{posquit0.bj@gmail.com}
\homepage{www.posquit0.com}
\github{posquit0}
\linkedin{posquit0}
\position{Software Engineer{\enskip\cdotp\enskip}Security Expert}
\quote{``Make the change that you want to see in the world."}
\makecvfooter{\today}{Claud D. Park~~~•~~~Résumé}{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\makecvheader 
\input{cv-sections/education.tex}
\input{cv-sections/skills.tex}
\input{cv-sections/experience.tex}
\end{document}
```

Sorry, i don't even know where to begin to look and what parts you'd like me to show to you.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Please always provide a small working example (MWE).  It helps us to help you.  In your case, you seem to load a package by `\usepackage[vargreek-shape]{somepackage}` which seems not to be defined.  Maybe a simple typo, maybe something else.  Hard to say without the complete example.

Comment: The template is outdated and should be corrected. The option has been removed from a current unicode-math: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351955/compilation-error-option-unknown-can-anyone-help-me/352094#352094

Comment: I realize it is outdated from previous answers, but is there a way to modify it so that I can still use it?

Comment: The code has already been corrected: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/commit/6e8586270b203d5861377ba017f30cf16ed425cc. So simply get the newest version.

Comment: I have downloaded the most updated version of the template and while I can edit it online on overleaf, I can't compile without this error
! LaTeX Error: \usepackage before \documentclass.
I understand that \usepackage should come after \documentclass but in the newest version the creator uses \Providesclass.
I would like to know where the problem lies and why it can still work on Overleaf and not on TeXworks when compiled with Xelatex.

Comment: This is the link to the project
https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV

Answer (score 35):

There is a new version of the template.

Check here: https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/commit/6e8586270b203d5861377ba017f30cf16ed425cc

You have to replace line 1) with line 2) and you will get it fixed:

1) `\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}`

2) `\RequirePackage{unicode-math}`

Comment: FYI, I made the listed change in the **awesome-cv.cls** file (the subject squawk was first seen after I upgraded from **Debian Stretch** to **Debian Buster**). Also, FYI, I'm currently still using **Version 1.1** of the subject template...

Answer (score 6):

I managed to fix this issue by *commenting out* the below line in `coverletter.cls` and `awesome-cv.cls`

```
% comment out this line which causes this issue
%\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
```

And add a new statement

```
% add this instead
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
```

---

As Consuelo mentioned, the corresponding fix can be found in [this git commit](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/commit/6e8586270b203d5861377ba017f30cf16ed425cc)