# Migrating from TexLive to MacTeX: My scripts do not work. Undefined control sequence \end{document}

Tags: texlive, mac, mactex

I have classes for all the kinds of documents I usually write in Latex. I just migrated to a Mac in my new job, and find that none of my scripts work with MacTex 2018 (first time working with MacTex...).

The only error I get is:

> Undefined control sequence. \end{document}

Which means that there is something wrong with my `.cls` file, but that error makes it impossible to debug it.

The funny thing is all my files work perfectly in my Ubuntu machine under TexLive 2018. Why don't they work on a Mac?

Please have a look at this MWE of a simple letter.

This would be my `.cls` file:

```
\ProvidesClass{DC_cover}[2018/08/31 cover class]
\LoadClass{article}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
    \PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{gray60}{HTML}{666666}% 60%
\definecolor{gray40}{HTML}{999999}% 40%
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{A589D9}
\definecolor{skype}{HTML}{12A5F4}

\ifdefined\@cv@print
    \colorlet{myblue}{gray60}
    \colorlet{skype}{gray40}
\else
    \colorlet{myblue}{myblue}
    \colorlet{skype}{skype}
\fi
    \colorlet{textcolor}{gray60}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%hyperref options, no border and url colors
\hypersetup{%
    pdfborder = {0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
    urlcolor=myblue
}

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Arial}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{Arial Black}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{Lato Hairline}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{Impact}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{textcolor}}

\usepackage{unicode-math} %https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353136/compilation-error-option-unknown-unicode-math
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

%%%%%%%%%%%
% Awesome %
%%%%%%%%%%%

%http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/fonts/fontawesome5/doc/fontawesome5.pdf
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
%- If you want to use the latest, download fontawesome latest Desktop version from https://fontawesome.com/
%- Uncompress and change the names to the otf files so that they do not contain spaces
%- Copy the otf files to the following location, replacing current files
%sudo cp Font* /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome5
%sudo texhash

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% From Details %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\fromdetails}[5]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        \today \\[\normalbaselineskip]
        \textbf{#1}\\
        #2\\
        {\Large \textcolor{gray40}{\faPhoneSquare}} #3\\
        \href{mailto:#4}{{\large \textcolor{gray40}{\faEnvelope}} {\small #4}}\\
        \href{skype:#5?call}{{\Large \textcolor{skype}{\faSkype}} {\small #5}}
    \end{tabular}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% To Details %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\todetails}[2]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
        \textbf{#1}\\
        #2
    \end{tabular}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Signature %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\newcommand{\signature}[2]{%
%   \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
%       Yours sincerely,\\[2\normalbaselineskip]
%       \includegraphics[width=5cm]{#2}\\[\normalbaselineskip]
%       #1
%   \end{tabular}
%}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%Geometry etc%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% No paragraph indentation
\setlength{\parskip}{.5\baselineskip plus 0.1\baselineskip minus 0.1\baselineskip}

%%Page geometry
\usepackage[left=2cm,top=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Footer %
%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{fancyhdr, lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\setlength{\footskip}{1cm}

\newcommand{\footer}[2]{%
    \fancyfoot[L]{{\small \textcolor{gray60}{\faFingerprint}\ \textbf{ #1}}\hspace{0.375cm}-\hspace{0.375cm}cover letter}

    \fancyfoot[R]{
        \href{mailto:#2}{\textcolor{gray40}{{\small \faEnvelopeOpen}}\ {\footnotesize #2}}\hspace{3cm}
        {\small \textcolor{gray40}{\faFileSignature}\ \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}}
}
```

And this would be my `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{DC_cover}%[print] for print option
%letterpaper: US letter (215.9mm x 279.4mm) - default in this distribution
%a4paper: A4 paper (210.0mm x 297.0mm)

%%%%%BEGIN DOCUMENT!

\begin{document}

%%PRINT FOOTER

\footer
    {John Doe}
    {doe\_doe@gmail.com}

%%FROM DETAILS

\fromdetails
    {John Doe}
    {Some address\\
        1 Abc St\\\\
        Singapore 000000}
    {+65 1234 5678}
    {doe\_doe@gmail.com}
    {doe.doe}

\bigskip

%%TO DETAILS

\todetails
    {Jane Doe}
    {Doe Agency\\
        10 Abc St\\
        Singapore 000000}

\bigskip

Dear Mrs. Doe,

\bigskip

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%LETTER CONTENT%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

in response to the e-mail bla bla bla

\bigskip

%%SIGNATURE

%\signature
%{John Doe}
%{images/signature.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Is there any obvious thing in the `.cls` file that does not work with MacTex? Sorry for its length but I am really at loss trying to debug it. Many thanks!

Comment: Are you compiling with xelatex? To do so, you can add this line as the first line in your tex file `% !TeX TS-program = xelatex`.  (above \documentclass) I do not have XITS math and Lato Hairline on my system, but commenting out the lines in your cls referring to these two files, MacTex compiles for me.

Comment: I compile with LuaLatex...

Comment: Which log file?

Comment: @egwenesedai trying compiling with xelatex, commenting the Lato and XITS line, and adding `% !TeX TS-program = xelatex` at the beginning, I still get `ERROR Undefined control sequence. \end{document}`

Comment: I installed MacTex from here (http://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) and TexStudio from here (https://www.texstudio.org/). That is all I have done... Does Mac need anything else for Latex to work properly? Simple documents do compile ok

Comment: Anyone has any clue of what might be happening please?? I am totally lost here and need this working asap...

Comment: MacTeX installs a complete TeX Live. How are you typesetting your document? Are you using a Front End or the Command Line? What engine are you using?

Comment: can you try opening terminal, cd to the directory, and run `xelatex foo.tex` or `lualatex foo.tex`, where foo.tex is your latex file? It works on my system without issue. Or maybe it'll give you a better log output.

Comment: This was really helpful, running it in the command line the pdf is generated without problems, but some things are not rendered like some `fontawesome` icons. I don't know why running it in TexStudio just throws an error and in the command line it generates the pdf without a couple of icons, but at least now I know it is a `fontawesome` problem. Thanks!

Comment: In the same line, I would need to replace Lato and XITS Math, cause I do not have them in Mac... What would be a good Mac replacement for XITS Math to write formulas?

Comment: The problem I have now, is that I have to download the newest fontawesome Desktop version from https://fontawesome.com and replace the old `.otf` files with the new ones, so the new icons can be used... However, in Ubuntu I found the old `.otf` files at `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome5`, but now in Mac for the life of me that I cannot locate fontawesome5... Any clue?

Comment: You may use `kpsewhich` to see where the fonts end up; the font in`texmf-dist` directory on mac is usually `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype` (if using the texlive 2018 version)