# How to solve process keys options issue?

Tags: cv, friggeri-cv

Actually, I format my Laptop and install the `Windows 10`. After installation I install the new version `Winedt 10.3` with `Miktex`. Now I want to update my `Friggeri Resume/CV`, but I am facing `\Processkeysoptions {unicode-math}`.

Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Friggeri Resume/CV
% XeLaTeX Template   
% Version 1.0 (5/5/13)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% Original author:
% Adrien Friggeri (adrien@friggeri.net)
% https://github.com/afriggeri/CV
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
% Important notes:
% This template needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX and the bibliography, if used,
% needs to be compiled with biber rather than bibtex.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv} % Add 'print' as an option into the square bracket to 
remove colors from this template for printing

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

%\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

%\RequirePackage{unicode-math}


\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.55}
\definecolor{skype}{HTML}{12A5F4}
\definecolor{html5}{HTML}{e34c26}
\definecolor{php}{HTML}{6c7eb7}
\definecolor{db}{HTML}{FF9900}
\definecolor{linkedin}{HTML}{1683BB}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib} % Specify the bibliography file to include 
 publications

\begin{document}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{FontAwesome}

\header{S }{K}{} % Your name and current job title/field

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SIDEBAR SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{aside} % In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\section{Personal Info}
\emph{Father Name} SA
\emph{D.O.B} 00$^{st}$ Jan, 000
\emph{Nationality} ABC
\emph{Marital status} ABC
\section{{\FA \faHome}}
A Road, M 
R
P
\section{\faPhone}
000000000000
%~
%\section{\includegraphics[scale=0.11]{linkedinLogo.png}}
%{linkedin.com/in/yourname}
%~
\section{\includegraphics[scale=0.11]{skypeLogo.png}}
{84}
%~
\section{\faEnvelope}
%1946@students.edu
%{ms@gmail.com}
sn\\@gmail.com
%\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com}
%\href{http://facebook.com/johnsmith}{fb://jsmith}
\section{Languages}
\emph{proficient}     English
\emph{mother tongue}  English
\emph{}               Chinese
\emph{}               Punjabi
\section{Computer Skills}
{\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} \LaTeX, Tikz, jPicEdt
Matlab, Mathematica, C/C++
\LaTeX Draw, Mayura Draw, MS Office
\section{Hobbies}
Movies, Photography
\end{aside}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Objective SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Objective}
researcher in my field.
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Experience}

\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2015-Present}
{US}
{Campus, US}
{\emph{Lecturer} \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Teaching Calculus, Differential Equations, Numerical Analysis.
\end{itemize}}
%---------------------------------
\entry
{2013 - 2014}
{AU}
{abc}
{\emph{Teacher Assistant} \\
\begin{itemize}
\item Assist various courses named "Numerical Analysis".
\item Assist Computing Labs in Department of Mathematics.
\end{itemize}}
%%------------------------------------------------

%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   EDUCATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\section{Education}
\begin{entrylist}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{2010-2013}
{Masters {\normalfont in MathematicS}}
{Abc, ABC}
{Specialized in Finite Element Methods}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}
%---------------------------------------------------
%\newpage
 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %  Research SECTION
 %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \section{Research}

 %%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 %% Research SECTION
 %%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \newpage
 \section{Semester Projects}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  Research Interest SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Research Interest}
\begin{itemize}
\item Differential Equations
\item Finite Element Methods
\end{itemize}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  Teaching Interest SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Teaching Interest}
\begin{itemize}
\item Calculus
\item Numerical Analysis
\end{itemize}
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%%  references SECTION
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{References}
\emph{\textbf{Name}} Dr(Supervisor)\\
\emph{\textbf{Email}} @mail.edu\\
\emph{\textbf{Phone}} 0000000000000000\\
\emph{\textbf{Designation}} Professor\\
\emph{\textbf{Name of University}}AU.


\end{document}
```

Comment: Do share the code with Minimal Working Example (MWE).

Comment: you have not shown your input, or the error message or said what the problem is. That makes it rather hard to help.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \Processkeysoptions {unicode-math}

Comment: That is a line of code, but it isn't an error message or any indication about the code in your document causing the error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am going to share the code.

Answer (score 2):

You *still* have given no indication of the error message that you got however I assume it is this error,

```
! Package keyvalue Error: Unknown option 'vargreek-shape' for package
(keyvalue)                unicode-math-xetex.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.533 \ProcessKeysOptions {unicode-math}
```

Which indicates that the template has not been updated for a change in unicode-math almost two years ago, searching this site for `vargreek-shape` will show multiple answers from the start of 2017 eg

[Compilation error "option-unknown" - unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/353136/compilation-error-option-unknown-unicode-math)

Just deleting the offending option `,vargreek-shape=unicode` from line 51 of the class file is the simplest fix, although the class uses several fonts that I do not have, so I got other, unreleated, font not found errors.

Comment: Yes, this is error I am facing

Comment: @MickyK if you had said that at the start you would have had an answer a lot quicker:-) also searching the site for an error message usually, as here, shows someone has had the same message previously.

Comment: I download the new version but still facing the same issue, don't know how to resolve the this issue

Comment: @MickyK I downloaded it to answer the question, why can you not do as I suggest in this answer?

Comment: Still Same error