# Why does copying my ShareLaTeX project cause it to not compile?

Tags: sharelatex, compiling

My latex project compiles normally, but when I try to make a copy of it and try to open it, it fails to compile. Literally nothing has changed between the two copies. Has anyone had this problem before? I'm using Sharelatex.com

Comment: Hi, welcome. A new copy on ShareLaTeX, or a copy to a local machine? How exactly does it fail?

Comment: can you add the first error message from the .log file?

Comment: It's a new copy on ShareLaTeX. The error message was 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! keyvalue error: "option-unknown"
! 
! Unknown option 'vargreek-shape' for package unicode-math.
! 
! See the keyvalue documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
l.385 \ProcessKeysOptions {unicode-math}
                                        
? 
! Emergency stop.
!...............................................

Comment: I have no idea why that type of error would only show on the copy. Unless you've also uploaded a new version of `unicode-math.sty` to that project, seeing as the `vargreek-shape` option was dropped in version 0.8 of `unicode-math` (and ShareLaTeX has v. 0.7f as far as I can see).

Comment: Me neither. I didn't add anything to it, the project was a resume I built from an existing template (posquit0's Awesome Resume), and I wanted to make two resume copies. When I copy it, it fails to compile but the original still works.

Comment: For the source of the error see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352094/36296

Comment: Now the difficult part: why do you get this message only in one copy and not in the other? I think I remember having read somewhere, that sharelatex does not move old projects to a new version of latex if there is an update. But if a copy is treated as a new project, this would use the new version of latex, including the update which removes the option  `vargreek-shape`. To test this, please remove this option and try again.

Comment: That method worked! the vargreek-shape was messing it up. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that ShareLaTeX keeps several versions of TeX Live around, and older projects will (I assume) use the newest version that was around at the time of the project was created. For that reason, the original version of your project works, as that uses an older version of TeX Live. But when you make a copy of the project, it uses the latest available TeX Live.

This is actually a bit clever, because it avoids problems for users resulting from backwards-incompatible changes in packages. In this case it causes a problem however because the newest version of TeX Live on ShareLaTeX has version 0.8 of `unicode-math`, in which the `vargreek-shape` option was removed. The original project had an older version where that option still existed.

But fixing this is simple: In your new project, open `awesome-cv.cls`, go to line 80, and remove `vargreek-shape=unicode`, so that line reads

```
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
```