# TeX Gyre Schola (Math) gives error when compiling the example given in the GUST distribution

Tags: xetex, unicode-math, tex-gyre-math

I downloaded and installed both TeX Gyre Schola and TeX Gyre Schola Math. However, the example given in the downloaded package, [here](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math/download/index_html#Schola_Math), fails to compile:

> The key 'fontspec-opentype/vargreek-shape' is unknown and is being ignored.

I have tried removing the options given to the setXfont commands to no avail. If I remove every option, the error becomes:

> The key 'fontspec-opentype/ScaleAgain' is unknown and is being ignored.

Is there any broken compatibility issue between GUST fonts and unicode-math package?

I'm Using MikTeX 2.9.6930 on Windows.

---

**EDIT**. The help command says this:

> The module 'fontspec-opentype' does not have a key called
>   'fontspec-opentype/ScaleAgain'.
>   Check that you have spelled the key name correctly.

Is it possible that the package for Gyre Schola is outdated and uses `fontspec-opentype` instead of `fontspec`? Grasping at straws here.

Comment: the vargreek name is from a _very_ old version of fontspec if i recall directly. You shouldn't have to get these fonts separately they should be included in miktex and so can be downloads as part of a normal miktex package management (I use texlive so can not give details)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351955/compilation-error-option-unknown-can-anyone-help-me/352094#352094

Comment: Yes, I knew that answer you link. I understand that option might be wrong but why does it still give an error when I remove all the options? ScaleAgain seems to be a valid option according to fontspec documentation, so I'm at a loss here.

Comment: The problem lies mainly with `unicode-math`.

Comment: texgyre math works fine with unicode-math you don't need any extra package. It is just that the document you found is old and written for an older setup but you do not need that to use the fonts.